# Imprimir ciclos realizados para encontrar un valor C++

Tags: c++

Como es posible imprimir en pantalla la las iteraciones (ciclos) realizados para encontrar un elemento buscado?

Este es un programa de practica para ejemplificar una búsqueda secuencial

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std; 

main()
{
int arr1[10];
int req;
int location=-10;

cout<<"Ingresa 10 valores enteros: "<< endl;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
std::cin>>arr1[i];
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Ingrese el numero que desea encontrar :";
cin>>req;
cout<<endl;
 
for(int w=0;w<10;w++)
{
if(arr1[w] == req)
location=w;
}
if(location !=-10)
{
cout<<"El numero se encuentra en la posicion:"<<location+1;
cout<<endl;
}
else
cout<<"No se encontro el numero ";
getch();
}
```

A pesar de buscar información especifica a este punto, mayormente encuentro información relacionada a temas de geometria que no tienen relacion con este tipo de busqueda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes usar una variable `iteracion` para copiar el valor de tu variable `w` cuando el número se encuentre en tu arreglo

```
for(int w=0;w<10;w++)
{
    if(arr1[w] == req){
        location=w;
        iteracion = w;
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo "interrumpir" el `for` cuando encuentres el número para evitar ejecutar los ciclos restantes. Esto lo puedes hacer con `break`

Ejemplo completo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std; 

main()
{
    int arr1[10];
    int req;
    int location=-10;
    int iteracion = 0;
    
    cout<<"Ingresa 10 valores enteros: "<< endl;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cin>>arr1[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero que desea encontrar :";
    cin>>req;
    cout<<endl;
     
    for(int w=0;w<10;w++)
    {
        if(arr1[w] == req){
            location=w;
            iteracion = w;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(location !=-10)
    {
        cout<<"El numero se encuentra en la posicion: "<<location+1<<endl;
        cout<<"Número de iteraciones: "<<iteracion+1<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"No se encontro el numero ";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, en efecto si muestra el numero de iteracion. De todos modos voy a estudiar ese ejemplo

Comment: Buen día, de hecho tu variable `location` hace lo mismo. Pero esto es porque sólo estas buscando con un `for` (Método secuencial) existen muchos tipos de algoritmos de búsqueda (Encontré [este documento](https://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~noell/IWI-131-p1/Tema8b.pdf) con más información) que funcionan de diferentes formas, por eso agregué la variable `iteración` por si acaso pensabas cambiar de método de búsqueda

Comment: gracias Heytale, voy a leer ese pdf. Te mande mail.